# How to add onClick function to action sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, onsen-ui

I am working on onsen-ui and I want to implement an action sheet that does something every time

```js
function show() {
  ons.openActionSheet({
    title: 'My Action Sheet',
    cancelable: true,
    buttons: ['Label 0', 'Label 1', 'Label 2']
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()">Show action sheet</button>
```

I click one of the labels. I've looked everywhere for an answer but none seem to work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Click function inside actionsheet buttons can be handled in such way.
try this.

```
function show() {
  ons.openActionSheet({
    title: 'My Action Sheet',
    cancelable: true,
    buttons: ['Label 0', 'Label 1', 'Label 2']
  }).then(index => { 



    if (index === 0 ) {
        function1();
      } else if (index === 1 ) {
        function2();
      }else {
        function3();
      }     


 });
}
```